# отсутствует связь между ESP8266 и Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, esp8266

есть ESP8266, на ней клиент, на Android устройстве - точка доступа.

Из браузера запросы принимаются успешно, из моего приложения - ни в какую. Если строку запроса в своем приложении меняю на какой нибудь значимый веб адрес, то ответ получаю, значит программа работает верно.

Нашел в сети, что андроид устройства с версией ОС более 8 не работают с http протоколом, только https, но как решить проблему связи?

За основу проекта брал эту статью [Nico](https:///https://neco-desarrollo.es/2021/06/esp8266-wifi-android-controller)

язык Kotlin

SDK version - 34

андроид устройство  ver android 9

До обновления Android Studio все работало, теперь перестало ((

Comment: Я полагаю, что на ESP8266 все таки сервер, а приложение на андроид - клиент. Действительно, для https нужен сертификат но это в целом зависит от того, как там сервер реализован. Похоже, что на Arduino c++ на ESP8266 можно реализовать сервер с https, см. тут например: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples/HelloServerBearSSL/HelloServerBearSSL.ino Еще тут теорию можно почитать: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-esp8266-https-ssl-tls/

Comment: да, смартфон - клиент,  а несколько esp8266 - сервера,  не понятно, как получить сертификат.  Открыть в браузере страницу веб сервера, а как она откроется без сертификата?  Надо попробовать..

Comment: Сертификат, чтобы его андроид принял, нужно у сервисов типа [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) заказывать. Let's Encrypt - вроде бы самый популярный на данный момент, потому что бесплатный.

Comment: оказывается можно и без сертификата https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/BearSSL_Server/BearSSL_Server.ino,  только не пойму где взять этот файл   #include <ssl-tls-ca-key-cert-example.h> или это и есть сертификат?

Comment: Это и есть сертификат, видимо. Без сертификата не получится, не будет работать шифрование. Вся суть HTTPS - добавление шифрования SSL/TLS поверх HTTP.